# Examples of theorems with proofs that have dramatically improved over time

Tags: soft-question, big-list, examples

I am looking for examples of theorems that may have originally had a clunky, or rather technical, or in some way non-illuminating proof, but that eventually came to have a proof that people consider to be particularly nice.  In other words, I'm looking for examples of theorems for which have some early proof for which you'd say "ok that works but I'm sure this could be improved", and then some later proof for which you'd say "YES! That is exactly how you should do it!"

Thanks in advance.

A sister question: [Examples of major theorems with very hard proofs that have NOT dramatically improved over time](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152405/examples-of-major-theorems-with-very-hard-proofs-that-have-not-dramatically-impr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Seems related to the earlier MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43820/extremely-messy-proofs.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, thanks.  I'd be happy to collect some more examples though, especially of proofs that (now) seem to be a particularly good "fit" for a theorem.

Comment: I guess this is such an example: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24913/quick-proofs-of-hard-theorems/24940#24940

Comment: I don't know the original proof, but I heard that the trick of Rabinovich provided a drastic improvement of the proof of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Comment: It would be also interesting to hear of theorems where people *didn't* think that the proof could be much improved, but then were proven wrong.

Comment: Many answers here so far seem to have the form "The original proof of X was very complicated, but now one can prove it as a simple consequence of Y." -- But if the proof of Y is not itself simpler than the original proof of X, should this qualify?

Comment: @LouisDeaett:  Good question.  There is something, though, still nicer about having a proof follow as a simple consequence of something complicated. It shows there is some larger (unifying?) idea.

Comment: @PeterArndt, Peter May has long advertised Munshi's proof of the Nullstellensatz as the ultimate simplification:  http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/MunshiFinal2.pdf.

Comment: I am not an expert, but what about Stokes' theorem?

Comment: @Yiftach:  Do you know anything about the history of the theorem?  Did the proofs get clearer/better over time?

Comment: @Manya I read a bit about it online. I don't know how complicated the original proof was, but I don't think it was trivial. On the other hand, the proof I have been taught 25 years ago used differential forms. There were some definitions and some one line arguments, but nothing difficult.

Comment: Maybe an anti-answer is the ergodic theorem.  There are now many proofs, and some of them are quite short (e.g. via Garsia's proof of the maximal inequality).  But, at least to me, none of the proofs are particularly satisfying or illuminating.

Answer (score 48):

[**Edit:** This answer seems to fit the title of the question, though not the actual question in the body.]

Resolution of singularities in algebraic geometry seems like a good example. Hironaka's original proof was over 200 pages and hard to understand:

> "Even A. Grothendieck [in Actes du Congrès International des Mathématiciens (Nice, 1970), Tome 1, 7--9, Gauthier-Villars, Paris, 1971; MR0414283 (54 #2386)] admitted openly that he did not completely understand Hironaka's proof."

That quote is from Dan Abramovich's Math Review of the book *Lectures on resolution of singularities* by Kollár; the review goes on to say

> "One can [nowadays] devote a few weeks in a first course on algebraic geometry to give just a complete proof of resolution of singularities in characteristic 0 (Chapter 3 of the present book, which is largely self-contained)."

I know almost nothing about this topic, but some names I know associated to the various approaches to simplification of Hironaka's proof are Bierstone, Milman, Encinas, Villamayor, Hauser, Cutkosky, Włodarczyk, Kollár, Cossart, Piltant... Please tell me any I missed!

Answer (score 39):

The prime number theorem, Newman's short proof is only three pages long.

Comment: As the title of Zagier's paper makes clear, this proof is due to Donald Newman: "Newman's short proof of the prime number theorem," Amer. Math. Monthly 104 (1997), 705-708.

Answer (score 37):

If you are prepared to allow an example from mathematical physics, then Penrose's proof that a ball moving relativistically appears as a circle to an observer. This had been proved previously by brute strength calculations with Lorentz transformations. Penrose reformulated it in terms of actions of the action of the Lorentz group on the celestial sphere. Since these are just conformal transformations, which take circles to circles, the boosted sphere appears circular.

Answer (score 36):

The [alternating sign matrix conjecture](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlternatingSignMatrixConjecture.html) was first proved by Zeilberger.  Zeilberger's proof was *extremely* computational.  A much shorter conceptual proof was later given by Kuperberg.

Comment: @Timothy: which of the three Kuperbergs? (I would bet on one of them, but it's not exactly the same as knowing it 100%)

Comment: @Timothy, I checked your reference (link above) to the end. It's G.Kuperberg (I would win my bet).

Comment: I am not sure there was such a clear order in the discovery of the proofs, my recollection is that they where found in about the same time independently.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner : Kuperberg clearly says in his paper that Zeilberger gave the first proof. But you are correct that the time interval was not so long. It is plausible that Kuperberg had already made significant progress on his proof by the time Zeilberger announced his proof. And the methods are so dramatically different that there is no doubt that Kuperberg's key ideas were independent of Zeilberger's work.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner : Zeilberger's proof was announced significantly earlier, but it was still being refereed when G. Kuperberg's proof was announced due to the difficulty of reading the proof.

Answer (score 32):

I think that Ax's proof of the [Chevalley-Warning Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem) qualifies.

The Chevalley-Warning Theorem is an affirmative solution of a conjecture [made by L.E. Dickson in 1909](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183420210) and taken up more seriously by Artin [I don't seem to have onhand much information about when Artin first got involved with this; if you do, please let me know] in the 1930's.  The conjecture is that every finite field is a **C1 field**: namely, a homogeneous polynomial in more variables than its degree always has a nontrivial zero.

Chevalley's Theorem is stronger than that: it says that if you have polynomials $P_1,\ldots,P_r$ in $n$ variables with coefficients in a finite field, then if the sum of the degrees is less than $n$, it is not possible for there to be exactly one simultaneous zero.  Warning sharpened this to showing that the set of simultaneous zeros is divisible by $p$, but in fact every proof I've seen of Chevalley's Theorem -- so in particular, Chevalley's proof! -- easily adapts to prove Warning's generalization.

(Warning's real contribution was a second theorem giving a stronger lower bound on the number of common zeros, assuming that there is at least one.  But that is not the result I am talking about.)

Let me be honest: there is nothing clunky or technical about Chevalley's proof. It is completely elementary, has a clear moral, and takes a bit less than two pages.  In an undergraduate course, it would fill one lecture nicely.

So how much room for improvement can there be?  Well, Ax's proof literally takes ten lines.  [See for yourself](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/SeminarOnCohomology/Ax.pdf).  The big idea is that $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} x^i$ is $0$ when $0 \leq i < q-1$.  You could safely assign the proof of this as an exercise in any undergraduate course in which you cover the cyclicity of the unit group $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$.

Can anyone think of another serious conjecture made but unresolved by mathematical luminaries which turned out to have a **ten line proof**?!?  I can't.

Comment: "Can anyone think of another serious conjecture made but unresolved by mathematical luminaries which turned out to have a **ten line proof**?!? I can't."

Was Little Picard conjectured before it was first proved?

Answer (score 30):

The [isosceles triangle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle_theorem) (pons asinorum), that the angles opposite the equal sides of an isosceles triangle are equal, was originally proved by Euclid by constructing several auxiliary lines. Pappus' proof uses no auxiliary lines, but only side-angle-side by "flipping" the triangle over to its mirror image.

Answer (score 28):

Jordan's proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem was complicated enough that people still argue about its correctness.  These days, an undergrad can prove it after learning the Mayer–Vietoris sequence.

Comment: Do you know a good online source where the proof is well explained (not just outlined etc.)? I am equally interested in good textbooks discussing this approach.

Comment: In typical US universities, undergrads do not learn Mayer-Vietoris, but your point is of course still correct.

Comment: According to Tom Hales, there Jordan's proof should never have been controversial.  An objection arose that he assumed the polygonal case without proof --- but that's a trivial omission! See http://mizar.org/trybulec65/4.pdf

As for the idea that a student can prove it using Mayer-Vietoris, I disagree.  Yes, a good undergrad can learn Mayer-Vietoris, but in order to use it here, you also need that the circle (or in generality, the sphere) is an ENR, which is a separate and clearly nontrivial result.  Remember, the hard case of the Jordan theorem is the fractal case.

Comment: What is an ENR? Also, can someone respond to my first comment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GH: Euclidean neighborhood retract.

Comment: There is a proof in my book "Topology and Groupoids", linking it with the Phragmen-Brouwer Property. Actually the proof is derived from one by Munkres in his book, but I think is improved by the use of groupoids. It was published in J. Homotopy and Related Structures 1 (2006) 175-183. (arXiv:math/0607229 )

Comment: There is a paper by Guggenheimer criticizing Jordan's proof that Hales was unaware of when he wrote his paper. But see [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344422/dehn-and-the-jordan-curve-theorem#comment932951_344422).

Answer (score 27):

Boone-Novikov theorem  of existence of groups with undecidable word problem which originally has very long and complicated proof now has several (self-contained) proofs of length $\le 10$ pages (see Cohen, Daniel E. Combinatorial group theory: a topological approach. London Mathematical Society Student Texts, 14. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1989. x+310 pp.).

Comment: Cohen's proof makes use of modular machines, rather than Turing machines. Though they are equivalent, it is quite a bit of work to establish this equivalence. I think this is part of the reason Cohen's proof is quite short; one must do some "pre-work" to establish the necessary preliminaries in logic.

Comment: @MCC: The fact that modular machines are equivalent to Turing machines is obvious and is explained in the 10-page proof.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. A while back I have been trying to find a reasonably short, self-contained reference but couldn't find one. The relevant section of the book is great!

Answer (score 27):

I think that Gelfand's proof of Wiener's $1/f$ theorem qualifies.

Comment: D. J. Newman's *A simple proof of Wiener's $ 1/f$ theorem* from 1975 seems so simple, I would be surprised if it could be made any simpler:
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-048-01/S0002-9939-1975-0365002-8/

Answer (score 22):

I described an example, Hindman's theorem, at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94546 .  The short version is that Hindman's original proof was unpleasantly complicated, whereas a later proof by Galvin and Glazer is now accepted as the standard proof.  On the intuitive level, it's a definite improvement.  Formally, though, from the viewpoint of reverse mathematics, Hindman's original proof is "better" because it uses far weaker set-existence assumptions.

Comment: I think Furstenburg's Stone-Czech proof of van der Waerden's theorem would also fit the bill. 

Answer (score 21):

There are several examples from Tauberian theory.  Around 1930, Karamata surprised people by giving much simpler proofs of Littlewood's original Tauberian theorems for power series.  Wiener's Tauberian theorems were later given much slicker and arguably more conceptual proofs using operator theory.

Answer (score 20):

A favorite of mine is the chirality of the trefoil knot, which can be proved easily using the Jones polynomial or some of its relatives. Louis Kauffman's paper "New invariants in the theory of knots", http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Bracket.pdf
explains this nicely.

I don't know how it was proved before the Jones polynomial, but quoting from p. 204 of Kauffman's paper,
"In the old days (before 1984) this was something that required a lot of mathematical background."

Comment: Is it the case that using the Jones polynomial sort of hides away all that mathematical background, or does it somehow clarify the main idea of the proof (give one a sense of why it is true?)

Comment: The first chirality proof, by Max Dehn in 1914, was indeed a lot 
more involved than the Jones polynomial proof. It involved finding
the automorphisms of the trefoil knot group.

Comment: @Manya, the Jones polynomial sort of falls from outer space. It's easy to prove that it's invariant and to check many facts using it, but why it exists is a lot harder to explain. But it does give very simple proofs.

Answer (score 20):

Gauss's first proof of the **Quadratic Reciprocity Law** relied on an intricate induction argument and was not particularly illuminating. Later, Gauss's third proof (based on the Gauss lemma) and especially his sixth proof (based on quadratic Gauss sums) gave more insight. Perhaps, the proof with the biggest "wow effect" was given by Zolotareff using his lemma expressing the Legendre symbol as the sign of a permutation.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, this question was essentially a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43820/extremely-messy-proofs, and the top answer there (from 2010) was quadratic reciprocity: https://mathoverflow.net/a/43831/11540

Answer (score 19):

Emanuel Lasker's original proof of the [Lasker-Noether Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasker%E2%80%93Noether_theorem) was 98 pages long, but the modern proof fits into a few paragraphs and is standard undergraduate fare.

Comment: Did anyone translate Lasker's article in English?

Answer (score 18):

Kurosh's original proof of the subgroup theorem for free products used messy Kurosh systems. This was improved by covering space proofs (or equivalently covering groupoid proofs). One might argue the Bass-Serre theory proof is now the right one.

Answer (score 16):

The Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem is an example.  As I understand it, the original proof published by Marcel Riesz was rather messy.  Thorin found a much simpler proof of the theorem using complex analysis about ten years later.

Answer (score 14):

Example of a bounded linear operator on a Banach space without non-trivial closed invariant subspace.

The first example was given bei Enflo in 1975. Enflo submitted the full article in 1981 and the article's complexity and length delayed its publication to 1987 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_Enflo).
Simpler examples were constucted for example by Beauzamy and Charles Read.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Read was subsequently the first to construct such an operator on $\ell^1$

Comment: Related: Aronszajn and Smith's theorem that a compact linear operator on a Banach space must have a nontrivial invariant subspace was later given a dramatically simpler proof by Lomonosov.

Comment: Did the earlier theorem also get hyper invariant subspaces, as Lomonosov does?

Answer (score 14):

The [Krylov–Bogolyubov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov%E2%80%93Bogolyubov_theorem) states that a continuous map on a compact metric space admits an invariant measure. The original article is 50 pages long, but nowadays this is a one-liner. This is because all the measure theory involved has been neatly repackaged in functional analytic terms.

Answer (score 13):

It occurs to me that Morse theory is a good example. At the time of Morse, algebraic topology (even the notion of CW complex or cell complex) is barely developed, which made his combinatorial arguments extremely difficult to read.

Well, nowadays people can simply learn these topics by referring to the definite account of Milnor or Bott.

Answer (score 13):

**Fermat's theorem on two squares** is another example from number theory where the original proof was clunky or technical, but more illuminating and "wow" proofs, such as Minkowski's proof using the geometry of numbers and the so-called [Zagier's one sentence proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Zagier.27s_.22one-sentence_proof.22), were later discovered.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest Gödel's second incompleteness theorem. The first theorem states that every consistent, sufficiently strong, effectively presented formal system contains an undecidable formula. The second theorem states that such a formal system does not prove any theorem that implies its own consistency. Gödel never published a proof of the second theorem, after logicians accepted that it could be proved by encoding a proof of the first theorem within the formal system in question. However, actually to perform this encoding would be technically very difficult. Modern treatments derive the second theorem very easily after establishing the [Hilbert–Bernays provability conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Bernays_provability_conditions).

Proofs of the first theorem have also been greatly simplified. Gödel's treatment required extensive technicalities to establish that certain existential quantifiers were bounded by a specific positive integer. These proofs can be replaced at the cost of modest other efforts.

Answer (score 12):

[Kottman](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm53/sm5312.pdf) proved that in any infinite-dimensional Banach space one can find a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of unit vectors with

$$\|x_n-x_m\|>1$$ 
whenever $n\neq m$. The original proof is quite messy, but there is a yet another proof, attributed to Starbird, which can be found in Diestel's book *Sequences and series in Banach spaces*. It uses essentially linear algebra and the Hahn-Banach theorem only.

Answer (score 12):

[de Branges' proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Branges%27s_theorem) of 
Bieberbach's conjecture was, if I recall correctly, one or two hundred pages. (And wrong, but correctable.) Now there is a [two-page proof.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9307209v1.pdf)

EDIT: those 2 pages are not a complete proof (oops!), rather they are shortening Weinstein's four-page proof.

Comment: And the shorter proof allows so much more opportunity to rant in the footnotes :)

Comment: Humourless note: the Ekhad--Zeilberger paper is not claiming to be a full proof. Rather, it claims to show how the proof by Weinstein (which is contained in a three-and-a-half page paper) can be made "much shorter" by two replacements. However, the second proposed replacement suggests replacing 8 lines of text in the original with ~20 lines (assuming the proof of the claimed fact is to be included), so the veracity of the claim is not so clear.

Comment: Another weird thing is that Ekhad--Zeilberger give a reference for the Weinstein proof which is correct _except_ that the name of the journal is completely wrong (Duke instead of IMRN). So much for computers being more reliable than humans!

Comment: Whoops! Edited.

Comment: @potentiallydense, calling E-Z's error in using an incorrect journal name "weird" or "completely wrong" is not fair if you know the history of IMRN. The Weinstein paper appears in issue 5 of IMRN in 1991, its first year, when every issue of IMRN was printed as the last pages of an issue of the Duke Math Journal! I remember first seeing IMRN that way and I found its appearance within another journal puzzling (i.e., giving a section of a journal its own journal-like name). On page 3 of https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2374838.pdf you see IMRN being introduced as a "new regular section" of DMJ.

Answer (score 11):

Aigner and Ziegler's "Proofs from the BOOK" contains many   good examples.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know  who down-voted what. I don't think that I did.

Comment: @Liviu:  Thanks.  Though some of the proofs in that book (as the authors themselves admit) are not necessarily the nicest or cleanest versions.  Are there any proofs in there that you think are particularly good?

Comment: My favorite from  that book is Sperner's proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

Comment: I also like Sperner's proof a lot. But the homological proof is surely at least as clean, it only uses more machinery.

Comment: With no further specification, this post is not an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 11):

PP (the class of languages decidable by a probabalistic Turing machine in polynomial time) is closed under union and intersection.  This was conjectured by Gill in 1972 and stayed an open problem for 18 years, til  resolved by Beigel, Reingold, and Spielman (BGS) in 1995, with a complicated proof involving rational functions.  The same result fell out as an almost-corollary of Scott Aaronson defining quantum postselection for unrelated reasons: the new proof is less than a page.  See:

- https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0412187

Comment: I disagree that the BRS proof is complicated.  Given the rational function approximating sgn, the proof is just a paragraph.  And the rational functions approximating sgn were mostly constructed already by Newman.  In any case, BRS give their self-contained construction/proof in a couple dozen sentences.

Answer (score 11):

**Tverberg Theorem (1965):** Let $ x_1,x_2,\dots, x_m$ be points in $ R^d$, $ m \ge (r-1)(d+1)+1$. Then there is a partition $ S_1,S_2,\dots, S_r$ of $ \{1,2,\dots,m\}$ such that $\cap _{j=1}^rconv (x_i: i \in S_j) \ne \emptyset$.

Tverberg's theorem was conjectured by Birch who also proved the planar case. The case $r=2$ is a 1920 theorem of Radon which follows easily from linear algebra consideration.

(The first thing to note is that Tverberg's theorem is sharp. If you have only $ (r-1)(d+1)$ points in $ R^d$ in a "generic" position then for every partition into $ r$ parts even the affine spans of the points in the parts will not have a point in common.)

The first proof of this theorem [appeared](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?extend=1&pg1=IID&s1=175510&vfpref=html&r=33&mx-pid=187147) in 1965. It was rather complicated and was based on the idea to first prove the theorem for points in some special position and then show that when you continuously change the location of the points the theorem remains true. A common dream was to find an extension of the proof of Radon's theorem, a proof  which is based on the two types of numbers - positive and negative. Somehow we need three, four, or $ r$ types of numbers. In 1981 Helge Tverberg found yet [another](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?extend=1&pg1=IID&s1=175510&vfpref=html&r=18&mx-pid=647358) proof of his theorem. This proof was inspired by Barany's proof of the colored Caratheodory theorem (mentioned below) and it was still rather complicated. It once took me 6-7 hours in class to present it.

What could be the probability of hearing two new simple proofs of Tverberg'stheorem on the same day? While visiting the Mittag-Leffler Institute in 1992, I met Helge one day around lunch and asked him if he has found a new proof. To my surprise, he told me about a new proof that he found with Sinisa Vrecica. This is a proof that can be presented in class in 2 hours! It appeared (look [here](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Tverberg%20and%20Vrecica&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)) along with a far-reaching conjecture (still unproved). Later in the afternoon I met Karanbir Sarkaria and he told me about a proof he found to Tverberg's theorem which was absolutely startling. This is a proof you can present in a one hour lecture; it also somehow goes along with the dream of having $r$ "types" of numbers replacing the role of positive and negative real numbers. Another very simple [proof](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=&s5=&s6=&s7=Tverberg%27s%20theorem%20&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=13&mx-pid=1845497) of Tverberg's theorem was found by Jean-Pierre Roudneff in 1999.

For further details see these blog posts ([I](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/sarkarias-proof-of-tverbergs-theorem-1/),[II](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/sarkarias-proof-of-tverbergs-theorem-2/)).

Comment: Dear @Gil Kalai: I fixed the hyperlinks in this answer. Also, it should be noted that all the links other than the blog posts require an AMS subscription.

Answer (score 11):

I hope I'm not repeating an answer already given (or worse still, an answer I gave and have forgotten!) but the solution to the derivation problem for $L^1$-group algebras would seem to qualify. The problem had been open since the late 1960s, resisted the efforts of several serious researchers, and was finally solved by Losert in a *tour de force* in the *Annals*:

V. Losert, The derivation problem for group algebras.
[Ann. of Math. (2) 168 (2008), no. 1, 221–246.](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2008/168-1/p06)

Some years later, Bader, Gelander and Monod obtained a novel fixed-point theorem for affine group actions on $L$-spaces, from which the positive solution to the derivation problem follows almost immediately (modulo some standard reductions that were known to specialists since the early 1970s).

U. Bader, T. Gelander, N. Monod, A fixed point theorem for L1 spaces. [Invent. Math. 189 (2012), no. 1, 143–148.](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2929085)

The same paper also gives *another* example to answer the OP's question. As well as giving a remarkably quick proof of the derivation problem for $L^1(G)$, the FPT of Bader–Gelander–Monod gives a very quick proof that every derivation from a ${\rm C}^*$-algebra into its dual is inner — this was originally obtained by Haagerup in his "nuclear implies amenable" 1983 paper, and the proof had been simplified by Haagerup+Laustsen in an article published in [1997 conference proceedings](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1656608), but the proof via the BGM-FPT leaves the earlier ones in the dust.

Comment: I'm not an analyst so I don't appreciate the significance of these theorems, but wow, that's good going for five pages!

Answer (score 10):

Witten's proof of the positive energy theorem using spinors drastically simplified the original proof by Schoen and Yau.

Comment: I think the proof of Schoen and Yau is short easy and beautiful and it is not harder than Witten's proof; other thing is that they might write it much better.

Answer (score 10):

Widom's formula for calculating determinants of banded Toeplitz matrices.
The original paper is hard to understand and uses quite intricate techniques.

Now, a quite simple proof can be found in Böttchers "Spectral Properties of Banded Toeplitz Matrices".
Actually, it also follows quite directly from the formula on Hall-Littlewood polynomials here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%E2%80%93Littlewood_polynomials

Answer (score 9):

The global (or homology) version of Cauchy’s theorem was given an elementary proof by John Dixon. I believe this is mentioned in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. A proof is available online at http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/CV/CV3.pdf. This states "The elementary proof to be presented below is due to John Dixon, and appeared in Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 29 (1971), pp. 625-626, but the theorem as stated is originally due to E.Artin."

Comment: Very good example because it also shows the *prize* to pay for elegance: Dixon's proof is so simple because it defines a cycle in $\Omega$ as homologically trivial if the index of every point  *outside* $\Omega$ is zero. But this hides the fact that homology is an *internal* property (invariant under homeomorphisms).

Comment: @JochenWengenroth, there's no elegance bought either. Cauchy's theorem is *trivial* once one defines homologically trivial cycles as boundaries (subdivide a simplex into smaller ones such that each it contained in a ball in $\Omega$). It's then also obvious that a trivial cycle is also "extrinsically" trivial - simply apply the result to $1/(z-a)$. So, what's at stake in Dixon's proof is the purely topological converse statement. This also has a clean and truly elementary (contrary to Dixon's) proof by Artin.

Answer (score 9):

Szemeredi's theorem and its special case Roth's theorem have been given quite conceptual proofs by Hilel Furstenberg using ergodic methods which I think is quite natural while the initial proofs were extremely complicated.

Comment: The original ergodic proof of Szemeredi's theorem is arguably not a perfect example for this list, since both Austin's and Polymath proofs of the density Hales-Jewett theorem are significantly simpler.

Answer (score 9):

One historical example that should probably be on this list is the Abel-Ruffini Theorem, which states that there is no general solution in radicals to polynomials of degree 5 and higher. Attempting to clarify the bigger picture of why the proof works may have been one of Galois's motivations for his development of what is now Galois Theory- and the proof we have now is quite insightful and illuminating.

Answer (score 8):

The original proof of Muller-Schupp theorem saying that finitely generated groups with context-free word problem are exactly the virtually free groups, is really involved (though nice) and uses accessibility and Stallings results on ends.

But there is a short and elementary way to prove Muller-Schupp theorem using rewriting systems, as was recently done by Volker Diekert.

Answer (score 8):

The Amitsur-Levitski Theorem (the standard non-commutative polynomial of order $2n$ vanishes identically on $M_n(k)$) qualifies. The original proof (1950) is messy, with no clear logical structure and takes 17 pages. The natural proof was given in 1976 by S. Rosset in a 2-pages article.

Comment: Where can I find the 60-pages long original proof? "Minimal identities for algebras" is just 15 pages long ( http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1950-001-04/S0002-9939-1950-0036751-9/S0002-9939-1950-0036751-9.pdf ), and proves AL (its Theorem 1) on its page 7. Does it rely on lots of other references?

Comment: Also, it is question whether Rosset's proof is really "natural". It requires a lift to a characteristic-$0$ ring, which is suggested by nothing in the statement; and from there it still proceeds to apply some interesting and highly surprising tricks. I think there is much to be learned from that proof, but "natural" looks different.

Comment: Darij, yes 17 pages indeed !

Comment: The paper is 15 pages long, and the theorem is proven on page 7. Now I am really curious how this adds up to 17 ;)

Comment: One thing I can confirm, though: the original proof *does* look like a mess!

Answer (score 7):

an example from number theory (where such simplifications are not uncommon), [Bertrands postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate)

> for any integer $n > 3$, there always exists at least one prime number $p$ with $n < p < 2n − 2$

was first simplified by Ramanujan and then later by Erdos who also proved a more general case.

another interesting case study here may be [Lindemanns proof of transcendence of PI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) which is subsumed by later more general results. as Wikipedia states "Weierstrass proved the above more general statement in 1885.
The theorem, along with the Gelfond–Schneider theorem, is extended by Baker's theorem, and all of these are further generalized by Schanuel's conjecture."

another "possible/controversial" famous/legendary case study here is [Fermats Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem); Fermat scribbled in the margin of his book that he had a remarkable proof, but modern consensus is that he must have been mistaken based on the 2020-hindsight of Wiles complex proof. however, strictly speaking, it has not been proven impossible that there exists a short proof.

it seems that later simplifications of proofs is a natural process of the historical/evolutionary progress of mathematics so that results once thought more arcane/inscrutable/complex become more accessible with the polishing/systematization of ideas/techniques.

Comment: "However, strictly speaking, it has not been proven impossible that there exists a short proof."  Well, sure, but for which theorem has it been proven impossible that there exists a short proof??

Comment: agreed. the question of short proofs is closely related to Kolmogorov complexity theory & Chaitin's incompleteness both tied up with undecidability. there do exist some results or so-called "no-go/barrier theorems" in the form that "a proof for [x] cannot use theory [y]".

Answer (score 7):

The first proof of the Hopf invariant one theorem due to Adams is very technical. It involves decomposing $sq^{2^n}$ as a composite of secondary cohomology operations when $n\geq 4$. Then Atiyah and Adams came up with a proof that uses $K$-theory which both admired for its elegance and simplicity.

Answer (score 6):

Manjul Bhargava's proof of the [15 theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems) was dramatically simpler than Conway and Schneeberger's original proof.

Comment: The bad stuff were given to a computer in MB's proof while CS proof was all by hand. Is there a link to CS' proof?

Comment: JAS, I think you are confusing the 15 theorem and the 290 theorem. CS never published a full proof of the 15 theorem because it was so messy (a sketch appears in Schneeberger's Ph.D. thesis), and did not think that the 290 theorem was provable at all. MB's proof of the 15 theorem is short and the computer calculations are pretty modest by modern standards. Granted, the proof of the 290 theorem by MB and Hanke is indeed highly computational, but again, CS didn't have a proof of it at all.

Comment: ah ic. I think MB proved something more general. For every subset $S\subseteq\Bbb N$, there is a finite subset $S_f\subsetneq S$ such that if a quadratic form represents $S_f$, then it represents $S$. Is there a link to the proof? How constructive is the set $S_f$?

Comment: There are several possible links; I think it's easier for you to Google it yourself than for me to try to post the links here.

Comment: Actually I tried googling. I am getting the 290 and 15 theorems but not the proof for the generalized ones.

Comment: For instance: http://hofprints.hofstra.edu/24/01/Bhargava,_Manjul_(2001)_The_fifteen_theorem,_and_generalizations._In_Proceedings_Robert_J._Bumcrot_Festschrift,_Hofstra_University.pdf says the proof is in a preprint "[2] M. Bhargava, Finiteness theorems for quadratic forms, in progress" Is there a location I can find this?

Comment: @Turbo: For the 15 theorem, see Manjul Bhargava, "On the Conway-Schneeberger fifteen theorem," in *Quadratic forms and their applications*, Contemp. Math. 272 (1999), 27–37.  For the 290 theorem, try http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/290-Theorem-preprint.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Godel's original proof of his Incompleteness Theorem was immensely more complicated [Aaronson's one-paragraph derivation](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec3.html) of Incompleteness from Undecidability of Halting Problem. Even including a proof of Undecidability of Halting it would be much shorter and clearer than the original proof.

Comment: I agree that the concept of computability does give a nicer proof of Goedel's theorem, but I wouldn't describe the situation in quite this way. Aaronson's sketch glosses over the issue of *expressing* the halting of a Turing machine as an arithmetical statement. A large fraction of Goedel's proof is devoted to proving the expressibility of syntactical facts in the language of arithmetic, and these complexities are not avoided in Aaronson's sketch; they're just swept under the rug.  So I don't think it's fair to say that Goedel's original proof was "immensely more complicated."

Answer (score 6):

1. Chirka's proof ("On the propagation of holomorphic motions", 2004) of Slodkowski's theorem ("Holomorphic motions and polynomial hulls", 1991) is much simpler.
   (Slodkowski's paper is not that long, but uses a lot more difficult mathematics. A number of people had previously attempted to give alternative proofs, but these turned out to contain gaps.)
2. The original proof by Baker that repelling periodic points are dense in Julia sets of transcendental entire functions used the Ahlfors five islands theorem (a very deep result). The proof by Duval and Berteloot ([*Une démonstration directe de la densité des cycles répulsifs dans l’ensemble de Julia*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-8436-5_17)), building on work of Schwick, takes less than a page, and uses only very elementary results (notably, Zalcman's rescaling lemma for normal families). Even for rational functions, this is probably the simplest proof (simpler than the original ones of Fatou and Julia) currently in existence.

Answer (score 5):

[Faltings' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings'_theorem#Proofs) (aka *Mordell conjecture*) can be taken as such an example. Different methods have been used so far with various difficulties.

Answer (score 5):

Some results by Donaldson were simplified via the [Seiberg-Witten invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiberg%E2%80%93Witten_invariants).

From Wikipedeia: Seiberg–Witten invariants are similar to Donaldson invariants and can be used to prove similar (but sometimes slightly stronger) results about smooth 4-manifolds. They are technically much easier to work with than Donaldson invariants; for example, the moduli spaces of solutions of the Seiberg–Witten equations tend to be compact, so one avoids the hard problems involved in compactifying the moduli spaces in Donaldson theory.

See also [this MO answer by Dylan Thurston](https://mathoverflow.net/a/218061/1532).

(Added Jan 7, '16) An additional piece of information I learned today from the [Zabrodsky's lecture](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/conf/zabrodsky_16.html) delivered by Peter Ozsváth is about the existence of exotic smooth structure on $\mathbb R^4$. The original proof was based on Freedman theorem and on Donaldson theorem. Results based on new knot invariants such as the Knot Floer homology (and simpler combinatorial descriptions of these invariants) can replace the "Donaldson side" of the proof by a much simpler argument.

Answer (score 5):

In machine learning and statistics, the technique of Rademacher complexities has a way of radically simplifying otherwise complicated proofs -- in particular those involving margin-based generalization bounds.

Some examples include Support Vector Machine margin bounds, which used to be proved via intricate combinatorial fat-shattering techniques of
https://homes.di.unimi.it/~cesabian/Pubblicazioni/jacm-97b.pdf
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.42.6950&rep=rep1&type=pdf
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397500001341
and are now proved in 3 lines (see the Thm. 4.3 in 
http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/
).

Another example is margin-based boosting bounds, which were originally proved via an involved covering and sampling argument,
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1024691352
and now has a very simple Rademacher-based proof (Thm. 5.7 in
https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/boosting
).

Answer (score 3):

DeMoivre's theorem. The pre-calc version of the proof relies on a lot of triangle geometry to establish trigonometric sum formulas and then uses induction. If you use Euler's Identity, it's a one line proof. (Of course, then there's a large amount of analysis implicit in the background.)

Answer (score 2):

See Ostrowski's proof of Luroth theorem in Schinzel's book "Polynomials with special regard to reducibility"

Answer (score 1):

The four color theorem’s first proof by Appel and Haken, which actually contained mistakes, was proved again much more succinctly and successfully by Robertson, Sanders, Seymour, and Thomas (see for instance [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/FC/)).  As far as I know, there is no better proof as yet, and unlikely there will ever be one, but who knows.

Comment: I had never heard that the Appel and Haken proof "actually contained mistakes" so I googled it. Wolfram MathWorld says "This result was finally obtained by Appel and Haken (1977)...no flaws have yet been found, so the proof appears valid. A shorter, independent proof was constructed by Robertson et al." This suggests to me that there are no known mistakes in the Appel and Haken proof https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Four-ColorTheorem.html

Comment: @David White: That information is incorrect. I personally know Seymour and Robertson (and when he was alive, Thomas). Take it from them, the AH proof had mistakes, which AH tried to correct later. But those latter efforts were never checked. Robertson, Sanders, Seymour, and Thomas thought it would be better to find a proof from the start, making sure to verify the proof each step along the way. Their proof has been computer verified by Gonthier using a proof assistant. Not so the proof by Appel and Haken.

Comment: @David White: Check this out from Gonthier: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/gonthier-4colproof.pdf

Answer (score -2):

Liouville's Theorem that there exists a transcendental number had its proof greatly improved by Cantor who showed that a mere counting argument suffices.

Liouville's argument needs facts about how rationals interact with polynomials, and makes use of the metric structure on the reals.

Cantor's argument merely uses the fact that each integer polynomial can be described in finitely many symbols and has only finitely many roots. And it uses this to deduce a stronger result: that almost no reals are algebraic.

Comment: I think the downvotes are excessive and have upvoted to compensate, but I also don't think this is fully an answer to the question: Liouvill's proof, while more complicated than the cardinality argument, is by no means "clunky, or rather technical, or in some way non-illuminating."

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think it's both clunky and nonilluminating. The cardinality proof shows that the entire issue really has nothing to do with approximations, rationals or polynomials. You could extend the definition of 'algebraic' in many ways (for example to the closure of the algebraics under $\exp$ and $\log$) and Cantor's proof would show with no extra effort that there were still reals outside your set, whereas Liouville's proof would fall apart. Cantor's proof uses less to do more, and in a way which is more generalizable.

Comment: In any case I added some of these justifications to my answer, so hopefully that will stem the flow of downvotes.

Comment: I think the key point, though, is that Liouville's argument proves something stronger, and with respect to *that* conclusion it's a very illuminating and efficient proof. So it's less "Liouville proved X clunkily, then Cantor proved X efficiently" and more "Liouville proved X, then Cantor proved X efficiently, and in retrospect Liouville actually proved Y - which Cantor *didn't*." I don't think this quite counts; if anything it's an instance of nuking a mosquito, which isn't really the same in my opinion. (Of course, that's objective.)

Comment: Doesn’t Liouville not only show existence of a transcendental number, but actually exhibit an explicit transcendental number?

Comment: @NoahSchweber What's the stronger thing that Liouville proves?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Cantor's proof also exhibits a transcendental number. It explicitly constructs its decimal expansion.

Comment: Oh I think you might want to reconsider. If you think Cantor’s argument produces an explicit transcendental number, can you produce the first few decimals, say 10 or so? That will involve enumerating all the algebraic numbers, and having their decimal expansions. Challenging! In contrast Liouville is pretty explicit. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number.

Comment: @ZachTeitler I just had this conversation on reddit, so you can have the first 20 digits! https://old.reddit.com/r/math/comments/ggx2vr/what_theorems_have_had_their_proofs_greatly/fq600u2/

Comment: @ZachTeitler Although not phrased explicitly, Cantor's argument easily gives concrete examples. For instance, suppose at stage $n$ we've determined the first $k_n$ bits of the binary expansion of the number $C$ we want to be transcendental. Fixing an appropriate enumeration of the nonconstant polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$, it's easy enough to find a sub-interval of the interval we've currently limited $C$ to within which the $n$th such polynomial has no zeroes. This isn't truly difficult, although of course Liouville's is simpler by far.

Comment: Cool! I am glad to learn these things. Thanks guys.

Comment: @ZachTeitler This is something Turing did in his first paper on Turing machines (to prove all algebraic numbers are computable).