# 0's in 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, digits

> Is 40 the largest number for which all the 0 digits in the decimal form of $n!$ come at the end?

Motivation: My son considered learning all digits of 40! for my birthday. I told him that the best way to remember them would be to come up with a mnemonic. He asked me what word he should come up with if the digit is 0. The rest is history.

Comment: Interesting question, but very difficult. I am not sure we even know if there are an infinite number of 0s in the decimal expansion of pi. (But it's believed this is the case)

Comment: Is there an integer n which does not divide 10 such that for any k integer with 10 does not divide a = n * k and a has a zero in its decimal places ?

Comment: And by the way, happy 40th birthday ;)

Comment: What follows doesn't answer your question, and probably won't contribute to an answer either, but a result by John Edward Maxfield -- [*A note on* $N!$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2688966), **Mathematics Magazine** 43 #2 (March 1970), pp. 64-67 -- might be of interest: Given any positive integer $n,$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that the decimal digits of $N!$ begin with all the decimal digits of $n,$ in their correct order. For more about this, see my answer to [Short papers for undergraduate course on reading scholarly math](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295704/15780).

Comment: Using the heuristic that *the digits of $n!$ are just random, followed by some zeroes at the end*, you can calculate without too much trouble that the answer to your question is: probably yes. My (very crude) estimate puts it at a better than 99% chance. I don't know whether this heuristic is any good, and I doubt this way of thinking will lead to a real answer . . . but there you have it.

Comment: @Will, did your back-of-envelope calculation provide any estimate on when it would happen?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen: I mean that 40 probably is the largest number $n$ for which all the 0's in $n!$ appear at the end.

Comment: Oh, I understood it the wrong way! My bad.

Comment: @Loïc Thanks, though a bit early, and it is not the 40th, but the 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000th ;)

Comment: I would learn a cyclic number instead, that he can use for magic tricks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number

Comment: @domotorp: oh, that's what I feared... :D

Comment: One could call it the [Zumkeller conjecture](https://oeis.org/A137582).

Comment: Then I suppose this answers my question as 'known open problem'.

Comment: Interesting... I could not find another example for $41 \leq n \leq 16000$. I wrote a small Python program for that purpose, which checked the $n$s in the previous range one by one.

Comment: As for the mnemonic, he can try to use 10 letters words, if they're not too uncommon in your native language.

Comment: Ok, it seems you're Hungarian. Well, finding such words should not be too much of an issue :-)

Comment: $41!$ seems to be the last factorial number with no digit 9 in it. It looks like for $n\ge 42$, the decimal representation of $n!$ will contain all ten digits, even after trailing zeros have been removed. Edit: Found [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A182049).

Comment: @Malkoun I did a similar check before seeing your post, and ran it up to 40,000.  OEIS A182049 mentioned by Jeppe Stig Nielsen implies it's been checked up to 100,000.  I guess I could check somewhat further by letting a computer run through the weekend, but I doubt there's much point.

Comment: The title would be improved (and less puzzling) if it were replaced by the sentence that is the actual question.

Comment: I changed the title to "$0$'s in 40!=...", that is, added "40!". This makes the title less cryptic within the list of questions. I regret you reverted it.

Comment: I prefer to keep an air of mystery about 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000.

Comment: The point is that the question is *not* about the zeros in this number (which is a trivial question) but about the zeros in infinitely many *other* numbers.

Comment: Maybe it will easy to solve in binary first. Where satisfied for 0!, 1!, 2!, 3! and 4!.